# Reusability of methods that use the @HostListener(...) annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

At the moment I am creating a front end application for my project using Angular. In several different classes I am listening for a user's keyboard shortcut to perform a certain action. In each class, these methods and what they do are exactly the same. Is there some way to move these methods into a separate class and have the original class send the short cut events to those methods?

An example of one of the methods:

```
@HostListener(HotkeyConfiguration.unselectSelected.eventName) escapeEvent(): void {
  if (document.querySelector('.filter') === document.activeElement) {
    if (this.searchComponent === '') {
      this.someInput.nativeElement.blur();
    }
    this.searchComponent = '';
  }
}
```

This method focuses a `textfield` where users can enter a search query for instance. But this method is used in 3 other classes, each class contains the exact same method.

Comment: Why don't use extract the logic into a service and call the service function everywhere in the `HostListener`?

Comment: @Batajus that would definitely be an option. At least the business logic would be encapsulated within a single class. But this does not completely solve the problem. I will still have the same methods marked with the `@HostListener` annotation in my component classes calling the service class.  I would like these methods to be encapsulated as well if possible.

Comment: What about an abstract class then?

Comment: You can't use HostListener in a service, it doesn't work. Perhaps using Render2 allow you to listen for the events. An abbstract class is useles since you can't write a static function in it. You could make a custom library that listen for this event so you just need to subscribe once in the FE and then spread the logic wherever you need.

Comment: @Guusda You can create a normal component, without associated template or styles that can serve as a base. It can have all the methods you need annotated and then you can extend this base component.

Comment: Angular directives are perfect for this. `@HostListener`s on the directive apply to the component the directive is applied to